# How to Draw Perpendicular line in Canvas html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have one Line with starting co-ordinate(x1,y1) and ending co-ordinate(x2,y2).

```
context.beginPath();
context.lineTo(x1,y1);
context.lineTo(x2,y2);
context.stroke()
```

I want to draw perpendicular line from middle of that line in Canvas Tag.

A Warm reply or guidence will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add your current code

Comment: i am just drawing the one line in Canvas Tag using below code
context.lineTo(x,y)
context.stroke()
and want to draw perpendicular line to that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates for the middle of the line are the averages of the coordinates of the ends:

```
var midX = (x1 + x2) / 2;
var midY = (y1 + y2) / 2;
```

The directional vector of the perpendicular is the same as the original line, except the coordinates are flipped and one of the coordinates is multiplied by -1 (which one you multiply decides whether the line will be clockwise or anticlockwise from the original). Add that directional vector to the midpoint and you have your perpendicular.

```
var dx = (x2 - x1);
var dy = (y2 - y1);
context.moveTo(midX, midY);
context.lineTo(midX + dy, midY - dx);
context.stroke();
```

This will draw a perpendicular that is the same length as your original line. If you want to draw a different length you'll need to adjust the directional vector. Read up on coordinate geometry and vectors for more details.

Comment: Working Perfectly for me
Thanks for your guidence

Answer (score 0):

To draw a perpendicular line you just need to rotate it 90º, follow [this question answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513786/html-canvas-drawing-line-perpendicular-on-another-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which contains some example functions to do it, like:

```
function setTransformToLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  const vx = x2 - x1;   // get the line as vector
  const vy = y2 - y1;
  const len = Math.hypot(vx, vy); // For <= IE11 use Math.sqrt(vx * vx + vy * vy)
  const nx = vx / len; // Normalise the line vector. Making it one
  const ny = vy / len; // pixel long. This sets the scale

  // The transform is the normalised line vector for x axis, y at 90 deg 
  // and origin at line start
  ctx.setTransform(nx, ny, -ny, nx, x1, y1); // set transform

  return len;
}
```

Comment: The Code is working perfect but I want to Draw the perpendicular Line from Middle point of the base Line

Comment: Well in that case you need to get the middle, for X
`var midX=line.x0+(line.x1-line.x0)*0.50;` and for Y
`var midY=line.y0+(line.y1-line.y0)*0.50;`

Comment: I already get the middle point of that base line.
I want to draw a perpendicular line from that middle point